# How to disable in CRUD create and update?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have statistical data I want to show it for users. I need only options to read (single and list view) and delete. How to disable the possibility to Create and Update?

Answer (score 1):

in the CrudController "setup" method needs to add         `$this->crud->denyAccess(['create', 'delete']);`